# How to start ARM programming in linux?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, arm, embedded-linux

I was using PIC micro controller for my projects. Now I would like to move to ARM based Controllers. I would like to start ARM using Linux (using C). But I have no idea how to start using Linux. Which compiler is best, what all things I need to study like a lot of confusions. Can you guys help me on that? My projects usually includes UART, IIC, LCD and such things. I am not using any RTOS. Can you guys help me?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: If you can read russian I can give your a link to my story about linux + STM32P103.

Answer (score 1):

Once you put a heavyweight OS like Linux on a device, the level of abstraction from the hardware it provides makes it largely irrelevant what the chip is.  If you want to learn something about ARM specifically, using Linux is a way of avoiding exactly that!

Morover the jump from PIC to ARM + Linux is huge.  Linux does not get out of bed for less that 4Mb or RAM and considerably more non-volatile storage - and that is a bare minimum.  ARM chips cover a broad spectrum, with low-end parts not even capable of supporting Linux.  To make Linux worthwhile you need an ARM part with MMU support, which excludes a large range of ARM7 and Cortex-M parts.

There are plenty of smaller operating systems for ARM that will allow you to perform efficient (and hard real-time) scheduling and IPC with a very small footprint.  They range form simple scheduling kernels such as FreeRTOS to more complete operating systems with standard device support and networking such as eCOS.  Even if you use a simple scheduler, there are plenty of libraries available to support networking, filesystems, USB etc.

The answer to your question about compiler is almost certainly GCC - thet is the compiler Linux is built with.  You will need a cross-compiler to build the kernel itself, but if you do have an ARM platform with sufficient resource, once you have Linux running on it, your target can host a compiler natively.

If you truly want to use Linux on ARM against all my advice, then the lowest cost, least effort approach to doing so is perhaps to use a Raspberry Pi.  It is an ARM11 based board that runs Linux out of the box, is increasingly widely supported, and can be overclocked to 900MHz

Comment: as far as i can unserstand, he/she wants to develop embedded programs for ARM architecture, on a linux machine; not to run linux on an ARM chip.

Comment: @sazary:  Quite probably - if the questioner was at all interested they'd have made that point themselves months ago.

Answer (score 0):

ARM Linux compilers and build toolchains are provided by many vendors. Below are your options which I know of:

1.ARM themselves in form of their product [DS-5](http://ds.arm.com/) ;

2.Codesourcery now acquired by Mentor graphics. See some instructions to obtain & install, codesourcery toolchain for ARM linux [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Installing_CodeSourcery_Toolchain)

3.To first start programming using ARM (C , assembly ) I find this Windows-Cygwin version of ARM linux tool chain very helpfull. [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/armlinux4cygwin/).  These are prebuilt executables which work under Cygwin(A Posix shell layer) on Windows.

4.Another option would be to cross compile gcc/g++ toolchain on Linux for ARM target of your choice. Search and web will have information about how it is done. But this could be a slightly mroe involved and long-winding process.

enjoy ARM'ing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the Beagle Bone development board. To start with it has few features like UART I2C and others also u can give a try developing the device driver modules for the hardware.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should question yourself if you really need to program assembly language, most modern compilers are hard to beat when it comes to generating optimized code.

Then if you decide you really need it, you can make life easier for your self by using inline assembler, and let the compiler write the glue code for you, as shown in [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler) article.

Then the compiler to use: For free compilers there are practically only two choices: either [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/)  or [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

There is also a non free toolchain from [arm](http://www.arm.com/) which when i last tried, 5 years ago, produced about 30% faster code than gcc at the time. I have not used it since.
The latest version of this compiler can be found [here](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/index.php)

You can also write standalone assembler code in `.s` files, both gcc and clang can compile `.s` into `.o` in the same way you would compile a `.c` or `.cpp` file.

Comment: Odd answer, as I see no mention of assembly in the question.

Comment: This answer appears to be to a different question.  Also you mentioned a commercial compiler, but never mentioned its name.

Comment: I interpreted the sentence `arm programming`  as `in arm assembler`,  now rereading the question, i missed the part where user1982535 mentions `using C`.

Comment: @clifford: the arm compiler goes by several names ( rvds, ds5, mdk-arm ), best you look at arm.com to see which version best fits your needs.

Comment: @WillemHengeveld:  The tags are always a good clue!  With respect to the name of the ARM compiler, it was not me who needed to know.  If it is at all important you should edit your answer, rather than address the deficiency in a comment.  The compiler is in fact RealView, all those products you mentioned are tool chains and development environments that include RealView.

Answer (score -1):

## Compile

If you are using a STM32 based microcontroller you need to get [CMSIS](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries.html) and GNU `arm-non-eabi-gcc` package installed. Then you need to write your own makefile to pass your c codes into arm gcc compiler.

## Programming

For the programming step you need to install openocd and configure that for your specific programmer. You can find a full description on how to do that on my blog
http://bijan.binaee.com/index.php/2016/04/14/how-to-program-cortex-m-under-gnulinux-arch/ and in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SecretTank/ARM).

## IDE

I'm using vim with CTags but you can use gEdit with the Shortcut plugin if you need a simpler text editor.